# useSearchParams() should be wrapped in a suspense boundary

Tags: next.js13

I'm dealing with a Next.js build error related to React Suspense and useSearchParams(). The build fails.

repository:
https://github.com/Mikitanjie/flower-shop/compare/2cc321ae52913e16959ffec93921661b68acea18..9c1df900874f95a865b9c83cfe7bc166ab6ce78d

Anyone knows how I can do to solve this?
Thank you

tryed to add the <suspense fallback=... everywhere where the erros points but nothing happen.
also tryed to downgrade some dependencies but nothing!

Answer (score 0):

What i did:

1. Comment all `<Suspense>` in the project.
2. Uncomment all `<Suspense>` (**one by one**) to differentiate the problematic one.
3. Strange thing! Relocate problematic `<Suspense>` into the parent component.
   (Initialy i'am wrapping all components into the `<Suspense>` inside the file where they are written, not in the parent component, hope it understandable).

*This issue may have different origins and different solutions, but this is how i solved the problem.